# USB сканер отпечатков пальцев

Tags: .net, usb, c#

У кого-нибудь есть опыт в работе со сканером отпечатков на платформе .NET (желательно C#)?

Надо: элементарный модуль, способный считать информацию отпечатка и сохранить её в БД.

Comment: Для справки - собирательное: биометрические датчики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Windows 7 можно использовать C/C++ [Windows Biometric Framework API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd401509(VS.85).aspx), который позволяет управлять процессом сбора отпечатков при наличии в системе подходящих устройств. В .NET API можно вызывать через Platform Invoke. [Введение в WBF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463089).